# mimic mouse pointer on second screen

Tags: mouse-cursor

Lets say I work on product x. To update product x I need to perform a lot of steps which cannot be scripted. Assume that 10 customers use product x and need an update. Instead of performing all the steps one at the time I was wondering if it is possible to duplicate/mimic my mouse cursor on a second/third screen so I can work on multiple updates simultaneously.

The target platform is Windows (10).

Comment: Might be useful to mention which platform(s) you are targeting

Comment: I looked google for your query. I found many softwares that can do this. While viewing randonmly, I found "Do It Again", install this and give a try. Hope it helps